# Error when I add 'throws' to a function in Swift: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ";"

Tags: swift, swift2

I am following this guide:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

```
    func canThrowAnError() throws {
        // this function may or may not throw an error
    }
```

I get the error:

> Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ";"[image]

If I click to fix it, it just puts a semi-colon before throws, which makes no sense.

Comment: Update Xcode. This feature appeared with Swift 2 in Xcode 7.

Comment: Thanks. Will I just answer my own question then and accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new `throw` feature appeared with Swift 2 in Xcode 7.

If you see this error it means that you're using an older version of Xcode, and you should update Xcode to the last version to be able to use it.

*Note: this was originally a comment, but since it seems of interest I've made it into an answer so it won't get randomly deleted later (comments are not safe to keep info).*